# Bootstrap - div spacing issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

***Question background:***

I am developing a site and have run into an issue with the responsive columns when the page is re-sized to a mobile device.

The following screenshot shows the site when viewed on a browser fully expanded:

[image]

This is fine and is spaced correctly, albeit slightly right aligned compared to the images above it.

***The issues:***

When the page is re-sized to a mobile device the horizontal `margin:auto` styling of the text is lost at the bottom of the div to the footer (as denoted by the blue arrow). There is also a margin issue between the bottom of the 'CSS3' image and the Top of the 'Test' text, as denoted by the green arrow. The space is too large compared to that of the horizontal break and the top pf the 'CSS3' image (red lines).

[image]

***HTML & CSS:***

**HTML markup:**

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4 testImage">
            <img src="~/Images/badge_css3.jpg" class="img-circle center-block" alt="CSS3">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8 testDescription pull-right">
            <h2>Test</h2>
            Donec commodo fringilla risus ut tincidunt. Vivamus consectetur metus ex, vel fringilla dui venenatis nec. Quisque tempus in nunc vitae tempus. Curabitur at tempor ipsum. In lobortis, quam facilisis lobortis ultrices, nibh velit varius odio, sit amet accumsan odio nisl non ante. Nunc sollicitudin in urna et viverra. Duis tristique nunc a turpis viverra blandit. Maecenas blandit ultrices varius.
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS styling:**

```
.testDescription
{
  margin:auto;
}

.testImage
{
  padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

Any advice sortng these issues out would be most welcome!

**Edit:**

From Christina's answer I was ableto resolve my issues:

[image]

Comment: If possible, can you show it on [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new) ??

Comment: why would you pull-right on a floated left column? Try without that  and put the text in a <p>. Bootstrap's vertical spacing is based on the top and bottom margins of the content inside columns, such as p, h1-h6, ul, etc., if your bottom element is inline, then you need to make your own either at the max-width -- that is make a media query, or put it in outside the media query and zero it out in the min-width

Comment: That is, you don't even need to use .testDescription custom styles for this. Why would you put a md-12 around the entire group? Where is the row? This is not normal Bootstrap mark up

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting - you never nest without another row or you get double padding issues and clearing issues. That's probably why you have that pull-right. You also don't need a md-12 on that layout, just use a row, things will line up and remove the pull right

Comment: In Bootstrap, the <h2> has an automatic `padding-top: 20px`, which could be why you see a difference in separation.  With regard to the blue arrow, I do not know what is wrong; please explain what you would like to see instead.

Comment: @pred There's no padding on the h1-h6, p, ul, ol, it's margin. There's a difference in behavior, particularly with box-sizing:border-box which is global.

Comment: @Christina You are correct, my bad :)

Comment: @Christina Many thanks for your answer. I removed the slight right alignment issue I had by removing the 'pull-right' styling' removing the redundant 'myDescription' styling and wrapping the 4/8 cols in a 'row'. I then altered my media query until I produced the output I have shown in my edit. Please set an answer to the question and i'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @Christina you should add that as an answer, it's correct by all means and not only solves the issue, but it also explains the reason why it happens, which is very useful for other users visiting this question in the future