# Bootstrap remove block element spacing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the twitter bootstrap and I have some divs as in the following image:

[image]

How can I position them so that there are no gaps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827438/bootstrap-div-spacing-issues

Comment: That is normal float behavior. Learn about floats. All heights must be the same height or you can use a variety of scripts, Masonry is the top choice, or you can use Flexbox. Google masonry layouts

Comment: Also become familiar with caniuse.com since flexbox is modern browsers only.

Comment: Shuffle.js works, read the docs here: http://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/ -- Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/3pb3n1xa/